# Architecture options for CouchDB messaging app

Tags: architecture, couchdb, messaging

I have a question with regard to the most appropriate architecture on couchDB for a Messaging app use case I have.

The use case is for a simple messaging platform which currently has one couch DB with all messages as documents.  Each document has a “to” field indicating the intended recipients of the message.  When a client app wakes up it queries the database for all new messages addressed to the specific user after the last check.  This is achieved by querying the _changes feed with a normal filter checking for the presence of the user's id in a “to” field in the document.

As I understand couchDB’s operation, this requires the database to retrieve all documents for the changes feed after the last sequence and run the filter function against them.  Since the likelihood of a new message in my use case is quite low, this would result in quite a large overhead (Lets say I have 100 000 users each getting two messages per day, it will require the DB to read all 200 000 message 200 000 times to support all users?)

Option 1: From what I read it is not possible to put a parametric filter on top of the _changes feed.  This would be nice, since then I would have been able to use replication functionality to extract the messages. – Non Starter?

Option 2: Implement a view with a key combining the “to” field and the update sequence. I can then query this view for the user value and sequence > last sequence. – Here I am struggling to gain access to the document's update Seq from the  Map function.  – Is this viable?

Option 3: Implement a database on the server for each user and set up replication on the common database to each user specific database.  The user then queries the _changes feed of her own database which only has messages directed to her, so easy.  Now you need to maintain 100 000 x 2 replications on the server.  This has other drawbacks, but could work.

From the above, which sounds like the most feasible/scaleable approach?  Or am I missing another option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with option 2. Instead of the document sequence ID (which I don't think you can get from view functions), just add a date/time field to your message documents?

If you're worried about clock skew in your clients (which you should have posted as a comment to my answer instead of trying to edit it, which got rejected), you can just apply some tolerance in the retrieval. I'm assuming it wouldn't be too bad to just pull in a few extra messages you've already seen.

(I also wouldn't worry that much about clock skew, but I don't know what kind of clients you're going to be working with.)